# File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, vim

Tags: emacs, vim-plugin

I attempted to install emacs vim mode via these QuickStart instructions for it at the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VimMode).

Namely, I downloaded [vim-mode](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/vim-mode), placed it at `~/.emacs.d/vim-mode`, and placed the following into my emacs init file

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/matthew/vim-mode")
(require 'vim)
(vim-mode 1)
```

Now when I open emacs it says it can't find 'vim', showing the following error

[image]

What can I do to proceed and use vim mode in my emacs?

Comment: That should be `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vim-mode")`, right?

Comment: You're right I had the wrong path. Thanks. Wow.